# Unable to add web parts to certain pages in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part

Are there two different types of Pages in Sharepoint?

I'm using SharePoint Online, and when I click Add Page, sometimes I get a full (ribbon) editor that allows for web parts, etc. Other times I get an editor that only allows me to embed documents, or a Yammer feed (no ribbon). I can't replicate how I got to the first kind, the second page type I access by clicking the Gear, and clicking 'Add a Page'

[image: Simple Add Page View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it appears this has changed somewhat, I'm having the same issue, from the site contents, go to site pages, then from there you can select new > web part pages, this will give you the old traditional style page, I'm not sure on the differences but will be doing some research on this

Comment: I had this problem too, cheers Damj. This is literally the stupidest change that's been made to SPO and as you all know that's some pretty serious competition.